# How can I sort best selling products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want sort best selling products in shop page
how can I do this?

Comment: Most sales product

Comment: To sort by sales just go in your settings - https://prnt.sc/GiE9-Wq9pKkv

Answer (score 1):

Use **total_sales** for 'meta_key' and **meta_value_num** for 'orderby'

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$product_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $product_query ->have_posts() ) : $product_query ->the_post();
    ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

For **specific category or sub-category**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => array($categories_id)
        ),
    )
);
$product_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $product_query ->have_posts() ) : $product_query ->the_post();
    ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

For **woo-commerce default query**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args','woocommerce_catalog_orderby' ); 
function woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    $args['meta_key']  = 'total_sales';
    $args['orderby']   = 'meta_value_num';
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this?function.php?

Comment: If you want to sort in woo-commerce default query, then use this code 

`add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
        $args['meta_key']  = 'total_sales';
        $args['orderby']    = 'meta_value_num';
  return $args;
 }`

Comment: How would you get the best-selling product from a specific category or sub-category?

Comment: @mjcoder I added the code block for a specific category or sub-category. I hope you will find this helpful.